# g++ -shared -fPIC helloworld.cpp -o ./hw, core dumped

Tags: g++, fpic

I build a hello world program with the following command:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC helloworld.cpp -o hw
```

When I try to run it with `./hw` I get an

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Why does it happen?

When I compile it like so:

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o hw
./hw
```

it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command builds a shared library instead of a executable file. Shared libraries are different from normal executable files. They ([usually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4963029/4098326)) cannot be executed directly, but can be used by other programs.