# Defining "main" by a function pointer

Tags: c++, c, linker, linker-scripts

In C++, is it possible for main to be defined by a function pointer? For example:

```
int f(int, char**) {
    return 0;
}

int (*main)(int, char**) = &f;
```

This code compiles and links correctly, but triggers a segmentation fault when it's run. I believe that may be because it's trying to execute the value of the function pointer as code.

Additionally, if it's not possible in plain C++, then can it be achieved by non-standard features of gcc (maybe somehow changing the type of the exported symbol).

Finally, if it can't be achieved with gcc directives, can it be done with a custom linker script?

Comment: Why do you need such modification for? Maybe the problem may be solved with less effort?

Comment: It's not entirely practical, it's mostly out of interest. The application I have in mind involves templates.

Comment: Why did you tag this with both `C` and `C++` and never ask about `C` in the actual question? And why do you mess with function pointers? And why do you hate `main`? *Why?!*

Comment: This question should probably be split into two parts. One about C++ (which has been answered), and one platform-specific one about achieving the particular trickery you're after.

Answer (score 6):

Paragraph 3.6.1/1 of the C++ Standard says:

*"A program shall contain a global **function** called main, which is the designated start of the program"*

This makes the pointer declaration illegal.

Comment: That answers the first part of the question absolutely. The others still remain.

Comment: @jleahy: well I guess the answer to the other questions is "don't do that". it's not legal C++.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you try to do is not possible in c++. Easiest solution I can think of is to simply call `f` in your main:

```
int f(int, char**) {
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return f(argc, argv);
}
```

I also can't imagine a scenario where the above solution will not do.

Answer (score 4):

I can't imagine why you would want this, but no, it's definitely not possible with plain C++.

If you really need something like this, just use a function pointer that you call as the first command in main.

Answer (score 2):

With GCC you can pass options to the linker with the `-Wl` option. Then you can use the `--entry` option of the linker to specify which function should be called first.

**WARNING:** This will **not** do what you expect! The entry function of a program is actually *not* the `main` function, but another function which sets up the run-time environment and *then* call your `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux, & using gcc, you can declare `main` as an [`alias`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to any other function.

e.g., below code works (with gcc at least, not tested with g++):

```
int f(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) __attribute__ ((alias("f")));
```

Answer (score 0):

`main` <strike>is a keyword in C as well as in C++ and</strike> gets overwritten as the function pointer name in your program. main defines the entry point of execution. Hence your program does not have that function and overwrites `main` it segfaults.

Comment: No, main is not a keyword. Standard's paragraph 3.6.1.3 says the name `main` can be used elsewhere.

Comment: @jrok, ok main is not a keyword. I looked up the keyword section. Bit this seems a bit odd. How would one define another function as  "main function" to be the entry point of the program than?

Comment: nvm I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677337/how-to-make-other-function-as-entry-point-other-than-main-in-c) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Another "dirty" way is to create a fake function using assembly & as the first instruction of that function, jump to `f`.

Below is a `gcc` specific code for `intel` target:

```
asm(".globl main");           // main is not static
asm(".type main, @function"); // main is a 'function'
asm("main: jmp f");           // main starts here. jump to `f`

int g(){ //Some random function may be present in between "main" & "f"...
    puts("hello universe");
}

int f(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    puts("hello world");
    printf("%d arguments given\n",argc - 1);
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++) puts (argv[i]);
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd have thought that just adding int main(int argc, char **argv) { return f(); } would compile down to the same thing due to the jump threading optimization.

Comment: umm.. that's same as answer by Ivaylo. Approach in this answer is explicit jump; in case optimization is not enabled. We can however, confirm after checking assembly... :-)

Answer (score 0):

> int (*main)(int, char**) = &f;

doesn't look correct.

What about

```
int (*main)(int, char**) = f;
```

?

Comment: Functions are funny; the value of a function name is the same as `&function` (and also `*function` and other variants).