# segmentation fault by Special functions _init and _fini

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, init

For an observation purpose, I wrote a program using _start(), _init(), _fini(), goal is to not to use startfiles.
the code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test()
{
printf("\n%s: \n",__func__);
printf("library test routine invoked\n");
int a=3,b=2;
int sum=a+b;
printf("sum=%d\n",sum);
getchar();
_fini();
}

int _start()
{
printf("\n%s: \n",__func__);
printf("in library start routine\n");
test();
return 0;
}
int _init()
{
printf("\n%s: \n",__func__);
printf("in library init routine\n");
return 0;
}

int _fini()
{
printf("\n%s: \n",__func__);
printf("in library fini routine\n");
return 0;
}
```

complied with

> gcc -nostartfiles test.c -o test

and the output is

```
_start: 
in library start routine

test: 
library test routine invoked
sum=5
l

_fini: 
in library fini routine
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here I want to know why the executable gave segmentation fault?? Do I need to specify as it is end of the program?? If so, how??
What can be done to overcome the segmentation fault??
Another question is that these _start(),_init(),_fini() are only used when dealing with libraries???
Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_start` routine cannot return.  Normally, it calls `__libc_start_main` which calls `main`.  Then when `main` returns, `__libc_start_main` calls `exit` with the return value of `main`.

Since you're defining `_start` yourself and not calling `__libc_start_main`, you need to explicitly call `exit`.  You're getting a sigfault because that function is not expected to return.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c) for more detail.