# Why is stdlib required to link programs?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang, static-libraries

Take the following C program:

```
int main(){}
```

It's not using anything from the C standard library.
I assumed we could disable linkage through [-nostdlib](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

However, this results in the following error:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib -o main main.c
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400150
```

Can someone clarify what the `_start` symbol is and who is responsible for providing it?
How would one go about using  `-nostdlib`?

---

Per the docs, I have also tried:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib -o main main.c -lgcc
```

Same behaviour is seen with clang.

Comment: First thing to notice is that that's a *linker* error -- it doesn't mean it failed to compile.

Comment: @Dmitri Yes, I'll fix the title.

Comment: `-lgcc` must go at the end. Gcc processes libraries at the point it encounters them, so they are only used to resolve symbols from previously mentioned objects.

Comment: Why do you think it is? It might be required for linking, but not for compilation! And even for the latter it is not required.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29694977/417501) answer your question? If it does, I would close your question as a duplicate. If it doesn't, it might help to highlight the things that are different in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_start` is the entry point of the program, cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29694977/417501). The libc contains a little stub that reads the command line arguments off the place where the operating system puts them and then calls `main`. Thus, it is required to link against the libc in order to run a normal C program on a normal platform.

You can try to write a program without the libc, but then you have to provide your own `_start`. You can't do much though, you can't even return as there is nothing you return to. Your only option is to use assembly to painstakingly recreate the parts of the libc you need, like the `_exit` function.

Comment: "Thus, it is required to link against the libc in order to run any C program." - Sorry, but that is plain wrong! It depends on the environment if it is required. On most embedded systems it is not and there is not even a standard library to link with.

Comment: @Olaf An embedded system without a C standard library is not in compliance with the standard. Anyway, I reworded the answer slightly. Is this acceptable to you?

Comment: I honestly think my embedded code is very well "ordinary C programs". In fact,  don't find that term in the standard.

Comment: It very well is! Please read the standard **carefully** (translation and execution environment).

Comment: @Olaf The standard specifies that the standard library must be available even in free-standing environments (except for those functions that do not have to be available). An implementation of the C programming language that does not provide this standard library is not in compliance with the standard. Programs written for such an environment are certainly not ordinary.

Comment: A freestanding environment is not required to provide the standard library per se, but only specific **headers** which do not declare any objects/(functions with external linkage. Briefly: there is nothing to link for a freestanding implementation, as these headers only provide types, and macros.

Comment: Actually gcc **is** a freestanding implementation. It does not provide the standard library even for Linux. The glibc is a seperate project of the GCC (that name has two meanings). Alternatives exist.

Comment: @Olaf You convinced me. I hope the updated wording is appropriate.

Comment: As a proud embedded systems engineer (whatever that means;-), I cannot accept my primary field of work is something abnormal. Less as these outnumber PCs etc. by decades. How about deleting the answer and let time delete the question as dup (hope it does delete, does it?)