# Segfault in cout of a dynamically loaded position-independent exectuable

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault

I build a position-independent executable (`puppet` below), dynamically load via `dlopen`, get its `main` via `dlsym`, and call it. This works fine, as long as this PIE doesn't use `iostream`, specifically `cout`. If it does, the code segfaults with the stack trace below.

If I do roughly the same thing, but compile the puppet as a shared library, not a PIE (renaming main to something else), everything works fine.

What could be causing this problem? It exists only on Linux; on a Mac this works fine.

`puppet.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello from puppet" << std::endl;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from main" << std::endl;

    typedef     int  (*MainType)(int argc, char *argv[]);

    void* lib = dlopen("./puppet", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (lib == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open the library" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    MainType f = (MainType) dlsym(lib, "main");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to get the function" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int argc = 0; char** argv = 0;
    f(argc, argv);
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
all: main puppet

puppet: puppet.cpp
        g++ puppet.cpp -o puppet -fPIE -Wl,-pie -Wl,--export-dynamic

main: main.cpp
        g++ main.cpp -o main -ldl
```

Backtrace from the segfault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff795da56 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry (this=0x7fffffffe080, __os=...) at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc:46
46      /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) back
#0  0x00007ffff795da56 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry (this=0x7fffffffe080, __os=...) at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc:46
#1  0x00007ffff795e109 in std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> > (__out=..., __s=__s@entry=0x7ffff6ce0b95 "Hello from puppet", __n=17) at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib
stdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream_insert.h:76
#2  0x00007ffff795e5a9 in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (__out=..., __s=0x7ffff6ce0b95 "Hello from puppet") at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_t
raits.h:320
#3  0x00007ffff6ce0a87 in main () from ./puppet
#4  0x0000555555554a7e in main ()
```

Comment: Some sort of ODR violation? Are those `cout` objects the same in both main calls?

Comment: Please compile with `-g`.

Comment: @VTT Adding `printf("%p\n", &std::cout)` to both main.cpp and puppet.cpp shows two different addresses. But I think that's expected.

Comment: @S.M. Adding `-g` didn't change the backtrace since almost all of it is in libstdc++

Comment: `main` is not an entry point of an executable. Many initializing things must be done before it. What happens if you call `_start`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c

Comment: @S.M. Calling `_start` produces the same segfault.

Comment: @VTT Looking into it more, you are right. If I build not a PIE, but a normal shared library, there the address of `std::cout` is the same as in `main.cpp`. Any idea how to fix this in the PIE case?

Comment: Basically, executable programs aren't meant to be run this way. You can use the exec-family for that.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Unfortunately, I can't. Without going into details, I have good reasons for "launching" an executable this way. With C, this works perfectly. On a Mac, this works perfectly. It's C++ under Linux that's causing these headaches.

Comment: `main` is magic: it has multiple permitted signatures and isn’t mangled.  Combine that with dynamic initialization of variables with static duration and it would be surprising if it did work.

Comment: @DavisHerring But it works fine on a Mac. And if I compile `puppet.cpp` as a shared library, it also works fine on Linux. Somehow in the latter case initialization is done correctly by `dlopen`, whereas in the case of a PIE it's not. It's the discrepancy between PIE and normal shared libraries that bothers me, and that I'd like to fix.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think this is a result of updating distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, but the issue appears to be compiler related.

I switched from g++-13 to the older g++-11 and it works fine.