# How can I change entry point for a mach-o executable for a c++ file?

Tags: c++, clang, mach-o

I am trying to write a c++ program without main. Is it possible to change the entry point of a mach-o executable to a custom function (other than `main()`)?

If not, then, is it possible to wrap `main` to call my version of main before the actual C `main` is called?

Edit:

I want to my custom function to call the C `main`. If I gave it a constructor attribute or added it to ctor list then `main` will be called twice. I do not want that to happen.

P.S I'm building executables in Mac OS X High Sierra with clang version 9.1.0

Comment: YOu cannot write `int main() { return myfunc(); }` ? Just curious...

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux my function has to be called before execution of main in such a way that it should be my function calling C `main` instead of the compiler. That is why I asked if there's a way to either change the entry point or create a wrapper.

Comment: Why? What difference does it make?

Comment: You can write a static class and put your stuff in ctor

Comment: @elvis.dukaj you could put your function into .init section (in .fini as well) using attributes, don't have to write code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-e <symbol>` option of ld, which you can invoke as `-Wl,-e,_<symbol>` from clang. Historically, the entry point of a program would be `_start` from crt0.o, however that has not been a thing on Darwin since Mac OS X 10.8 and iOS 6.0, where the `LC_MAIN` load command was introduced (replacing `LC_UNIXTHREAD`). The "old" way can still be used, but would have to be explicitly enabled with the `-no_new_main` linker flag (which has a counterpart `-new_main`, should you ever need it). The duty once carried by crt0.o has been shifted to the dynamic linker, `/usr/lib/dyld`, which can handle both `LC_MAIN` and `LC_UNIXTHREAD` as needed.

So given a C program with a `main`:

```c
// t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    printf("test %i\n", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

You can easily create a C++ file like this:

```c++
// t.cpp

extern int main(int, const char**);

extern "C" int derp(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    return main(0, (const char*[]){ (const char*)0 });
}
```

And compile them with `clang++ -o t t.cpp -xc t.c -Wl,-e,_derp`.
Just be sure to either declare `derp` as `extern "C"`, or specify the mangled symbol on the command line.

You can also inspect the resulting executable with `otool` to make sure it uses `LC_MAIN` rather than `LC_UNIXTHREAD`:

```
bash$ otool -l ./t | fgrep -B1 -A3 LC_MAIN
Load command 11
       cmd LC_MAIN
   cmdsize 24
  entryoff 3808
 stacksize 0
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I want. Are you sure that I do not lose out on any functionality which I would otherwise get without invoking the `-Wl,-e` command?

Comment: If there are functions in .init section, would they be called? Otherwise, for c++ code author is going to be  surprised

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the `-e <symbol name>` option to the linker (`ld`) to specify a different entry point. The default entry point is not `main`; it's `start` which is provided by crt1.o and which, in turn, calls `main`.

Comment: Adding a `-e <symbol name>` would mean I would have to provide `nostartfiles` as well. But that would prevent linking to mac os's startup files (please correct me if I'm wrong). I only intend to create a wrapper for the main function (or any function that calls main).

Comment: @Rohit Actually no, `-e` works as you'd want it to. You can create a small hello world binary with `derp` instead of `main`, compile with `-Wl,-e,_derp`, and examine the output with `otool -l`. Notice the presence of `LC_MAIN`, yet the absence of `LC_UNIXTHREAD`. If I'm reading ld64 source right, that should hold true for macOS since 10.8 and iOS since 6.0. If it doesn't hold true for you, you should still be able to force such behaviour with `-Wl,-new_main`. (You could also force `start` behaviour with `-Wl,-no_new_main`, if you wanted to.)

Comment: Also @KenThomases, `start` and crt0.o have not been a thing on Darwin for quite a few years now. The advent of the `LC_MAIN` load command killed them off and moved that duty to `dyld`, the dynamic linker.

Comment: @KenThomases Man pages are quite a sad story, because Apple seems to neglect many of them entirely. The one for `ld` seems to have last been updated in 2011 - which was indeed before the introduction of `LC_MAIN`. :/

Answer (score 2):

You may use `_start()`
It sets up some stuff, populates the argument array `argv`, counts how many arguments are there, and then calls `main`. After `main` returns, `exit` is called.

Here's are a couple of references:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29694977/2302572

http://learningpearls.blogspot.com/2011/02/start-function-inside-c.html

Comment: If I use `_start()` then would I be able to link against mac os's libc?

Comment: Should be possible. I'm not sure if mac os has different implementation of gcc.

Comment: Does mac os provide with something similar to `__libc_start_main` (from glibc)? I usually wrap it when I'm working on linux and need to change the entry point.

Comment: Also, I'm using clang as a compiler and not gcc