# Correctly target MacOS 10.6 using the build tools from MacOS 10.13

Tags: macos, linker, clang, cross-compiling, dynamic-linking

Out of sheer academic curiosity I am trying to make a MacOS GUI application ultra compatible — meaning that it has to run on all versions of MacOS from 10.6 to 10.14; going beyond this range is restricted by the differences in Cocoa API and CoreText/CoreGraphics.
Unfortunately the app depends significantly on several features of C11, e.g. `__auto_type`, so I cannot just go and compile it on 10.6, having to resort to cross-compilation.

The problem is that after being linked on 10.13 the resulting x86-32 Mach-O binary contains 3 load commands in its header that the `dyld` of 10.6 cannot recognize:

1. LC_MAIN           (0x80000028)
2. LC_DATA_IN_CODE   (0x00000029)
3. LC_SOURCE_VERSION (0x0000002A)

My question is:
How do I tell the `llvm-gcc` linker to avoid inserting these commands, and e.g. substitute LC_MAIN with the more compatible LC_UNIXTHREAD, etc.?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110492

Comment: It turns out that `LC_MAIN` was the only culprit, for the other two unrecognized commands are just ignored.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/48252805/5329717

Comment: @Kamil.S It worked, thanks! This is indeed easier than manually specifying `-no_new_main`, so if you replicate it here I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-macosx_version_min` 10.6 as `ld` parameter. This will generate `LC_UNIXTHREAD` instead of `LC_MAIN` in your executable (among other legacy load commands you're after).