# can C _start function be made to call entry point function other than main?

Tags: c, gcc

Can the C _start function be made to call an entry point function other than main?

The reason is I want to have a preprocessor embed additional functions in every C program I compile. The embedded code might provide test functions. Or some special debug features.

When I compile the program I would like to tell _start to call the my_main function instead of main. If command line argument -test is specified, my_main would call the special test functions. Otherwise, my_main calls the actual main function.

Comment: Like the solution [is right there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c). What is funny, even the naming of the `my_main` function is the same.

Comment: thanks.  I saw that yesterday. But then got confused because of a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it *may* be possible, however it’s all up to the compiler if that feature is supported or not. So you will have to look it up in your compiler manual.