# Is it possible to run __libc_start_main from C code?

Tags: glibc, libc

Function `__libc_start_main` is defined in `libc.so` with below function signature

```
void __libc_start_main(  int (*main) (int, char * *, char * *),
                    int argc, char * * ubp_av,
                    void (*init) (void),
                    void (*fini) (void),
                    void (*rtld_fini) (void),
                    void (* stack_end));
```

In normal usage, this function is called by function `_start` which is defined in C RunTime object `crt1.o`.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to call `__libc_start_main` in C code?

Difficulties:

1. I could not find a way to determine the value of last argument `stack_end` in C code. The implementation of `crt1.o` is in assembly, which is able to determine `stack_end`.

PS: I am just curious if we are able to call `__libc_start_main` in C code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not possible because `__libc_start_main` must only be called once per process, and if you try to call it from C code, it will already have run or will be invoked later, a second time.  Neither will work reliably, and future glibc changes may break such code.

You should post a new question with the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, it is only for my curiosity and I am not solving any problem, mainly for education purpose. I agree with you ```__libc_start_main```   must only be called once per process. In my test case, I also provider function ```_start``` myself instead of using the ```_start``` from C run time. Function ```__libc_start_main``` is called from my ```_start```, I hope this make sure function ```__libc_start_main``` is only called once in my process. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Oh. You should not replace the `_start` with glibc, such changes may break with future glibc version. You really have to link with the CRT files that come with glibc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is one thing I do not agree with what you say. The ```_start``` does not belong to ```libc```.  ```_start``` is the entry point of the application, which can be  provided by the user. Most implementation of ```_start``` is purely to call ``` __libc_start_main``` from ```libc```.  If we can call ```__libc_start_main``` correctly, I do not see any problem of to use the customized ```_start```. However, it is not recommended to do so in practice. I ask the question manly for my education purpose.

Comment: In current glibc, the CRT file which contains the definition of `_start` does more than just calling `__libc_start_main`. It also runs the ELF constructors for the main program (for historic reasons). Overriding `_start` will have to adapted if glibc behavior changes (for new binaries, old binaries will continue to keep running unchanged).

Comment: Sorry about what I said, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c, the ELF constructors are called by function ```__libc_start_main```, is this changed in the ```current glibc```?

Comment: The startup file contains a callback function which invokes the ELF constructors, and passes its address to `__libc_start_main`.