# Why would a program depend on the glibc without invoking any functions of it?

Tags: c, linux

I worte a most simple C program `main.c` under linux, just like this:

```
int
main(void)
{ 
  return 0;
}
```

And compiled :

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

...happy, and got `main` exe

But when I issued the command

```
ldd main
```

It showed me like this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd78151000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3f53a92000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3f53c9c000)
```

Why would this program depend on the `glibc` without invoking any functions of it ?

Comment: The Operating System does not call your `main()`. It calls glibc's `_start()` and that code calls your `main()`

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c

Comment: A Timely answer.It help me,thank you.

Comment: And the specific mechanism that creates the dependency in your code is that when you link a C program, the name of the start-up routine is set by default to `_start`. (The loader, `ld`, has a switch for this, `-e name`.) That causes the linker to look for a definition for that symbol while it is building the executable file. It finds that symbol in the glibc library, resulting in a dependency on that library.

Comment: @pmg operating system does not call _start only jumps to the program entry point stored in the executable file. From there execution starts. Not related at all to `_start`

Comment: If you do not want to use glibc you need to write your own startup code.