# How does argc in C works?

Tags: c, command-line

`int argc`in C is an integer variable that holds the number of arguments that are passed to the program through the command line . Since we don't pass any integer to the command line while executing the program , then which component is responsible for passing the number of arguments to `argc` variable ?

Comment: On Windows, it would be the code inside the executable that calls `main`.

Comment: Note that `argc` is mainly a convenience. `argv` always ends with a `NULL` value, so you could count it yourself. And that's what the `exec*` functions do.

Comment: `main()` is not the start of the program.  The name of the actual starting function depends on the OS (for Linux it defaults to `_start()`.  So when the program is run the actual starting function retrieves the command line, hooks up stdin and stdout and stderr, does some other stuff and then calls `main()`.  That's why `main()` must take those types and number of parameters.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c

Comment: @ikegami: *all* of the exec* functions accept a NULL terminated vector (array) of paramters.  The kernel counts how many non-null elements there are and passes that as argc

Comment: @ikegami: because what you said implies the reverse.

Comment: @Chris Dodd, huh? No, not at all. I said the count is NOT provided to `exec*`. From that, one must conclude the count is calculated further down the path such as in the kernel. I think you misread what I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

The "command line" is input to a *shell* program.  It is that program that parses the line and forms `argc` and the `NULL` terminated array for `argv` and then calls the C program.

Comment: This is true of unix, but not of [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)

Comment: On Unix-like systems, the shell doesn't directly call the C program, although it does parse the arguments. It calls [`execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), and the arguments it passes to `execve` do not include `argc` (although obviously it can be computed by counting the length of the `argv` array, which is an argument to `execve`). `argc` is computed during the startup of the newly created process.

Comment: @rici Re "*argc is computed during the startup of the newly created process.*" By the kernel or by the process itself? This is not clear from your comment. /// Re "*the shell doesn't directly call the C program*", I'm not sure what you mean by this exactly.

Comment: @ikegami: for your first question, it's an implementation detail. My ambiguity was deliberate. But it's definitely not the shell. I don't see how "the shell doesn't directly call the C program" could be misinterpreted, so you'll have to offer your parse. The shell calls `execve` (or something which calls `execve`). Any other calls happen in the new process.

Comment: @rici, It's not my question, it's the OP's

Comment: @ikegami: so you're trying to tell me that my comment to this answer is not an attempt to answer the original question? That's true. It was an attempt to suggest that this answer is badly phrased, which is why it appears here in a comment.

Comment: Re "*so you're trying to tell me that my comment to this answer is not an attempt to answer the original question?*", No, I'm saying it's a failed attempt