# Linux executable file as shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile an executable file which i want also to use as shared library. When i'm clearly compile and linking it as "executable" - everything fine - file could start and work correctly. At this phase i cant correctly linking other libraries with it (tons of redefinitions in log). When i'm trying to add options -Fpic -shared - program copiles successfully, but starting with segmentation fault. How can i make it executable and "sharedlibrary" at the same time?

Comment: Can you show the errors? I have compiled libraries and executables under linux with `shared library` enabled, and didn't have the issues you describe. So it is possible.

Comment: A single file cannot be both an executable and a shared library.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The only example is `/lib/libc.so.6` ...

Comment: i've got some "solution" i'm just building my module as shared library with -rdynamic option.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong and @JohnZwick was too. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449987/building-a-so-that-is-also-an-executable).

Answer (score 7):

A single file cannot be a shared library and an executable at the same time.  But you can link your object files twice to make both.  It'd go something like this:

```
g++ -c -o module.o module.cpp # create an object that has no main()
g++ -shared -fPIC -o libmodule.so module.o # build shared library
g++ -o program module.o main.cpp # build executable
```

Or instead, the last line could link the shared library (in which case you'll need the library present when you run the executable):

```
g++ -o program -l module main.cpp
```

Comment: This is wrong: on many systems `libc.so.6` is both a shared library and an executable program.

Comment: Technically correct--the best kind of correct!  But anyway, 99.99% of executables are not shared objects and vice versa.  Let's say you "can" but also you "probably won't."  I also tried executing my libc on Mac OS X, and it cannot.

Comment: This answer is incorrect (at least on linux): see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1451482/50617