# CMake: Is it possible to build an executable from only static libraries and no source?

Tags: cmake

I would like to build an executable from static libraries (i. e. .a-files) only. This is possible, because the `main()` function is contained in one of these libraries.

The `add_executable()` function requires me to provide at least one source file. But this is not what I want to do.

Comment: You could just add a trivial source file that defines no symbols?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no way to do it without a hack. You need at least one *.c or *.cpp file.

What I do is make a dummy `null.cpp` file (zero bytes) and use that. You can also use `/dev/null` but that only works on Linux.

```
file(WRITE null.cpp "")

add_executable(tester
    null.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(tester
    -Wl,--whole-archive
    libtest1
    libtest2
    libtest3
    libtest4
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive
    gtest_main
)
```

Comment: I thought that there would be a "standardized" CMake way of doing this. But this workaround works as well. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: By using `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/null.cpp"` instead of just `null.cpp` you can keep your source tree clean.

Comment: this forces a re-compile/link of null.cpp every build.

Answer (score 14):

There are mainly two reasons why a source file is enforced by CMake:

1. To determine the [`LINKER_LANGUAGE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/LINKER_LANGUAGE.html) from the file ending(s)
2. Not all compilers do support an object/library only link step (for details see below)

And if you move the `main()` function to library please keep the following in mind: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

So if you build the libraries with CMake in the same project, I would recommend to change your libraries (at least the one containing your `main()` function) to an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html#object-libraries):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)

project(NoSourceForExe)

file(WRITE main.cc "int main() { return 0; }")

add_library(MyLibrary OBJECT main.cc)
add_executable(MyExecutable $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyLibrary>)
```

The [`add_library()` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html) lists a warning here:

> Some native build systems may not like targets that have only object files, so consider adding at least one real source file to any target that references $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>.

But those are rare and listed in [`Tests/ObjectLibrary/CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/ObjectLibrary/CMakeLists.txt#L19):

```
# VS 6 and 7 generators do not add objects as sources so we need a
# dummy object to convince the IDE to build the targets below.
...
# Xcode does not seem to support targets without sources.
```

Not knowing which host OS(s) you are targeting, you may just give it a try.

**References**

- [CMake Object Lib containing main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695527/cmake-object-lib-containing-main)
- [CMake/Tutorials/Object Library](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library)

Comment: really useful.. I had come across this tutorial https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library however never thought it can also be used to add executable in a very neat way..