# Static library built with CMake as .a with Emscripten instead of .wasm + .js

Tags: cmake, webassembly, emscripten

### TL;DR

How do I configure CMake and Emscripten to build my static library to produce a WASM and JS bootstrap file?

---

I have a static library being built with CMake that I want to build as a WASM library (and JS bootstrap) using Emscripten.  Simply using the Emscripten CMake toolchain and adding the appropriate compiler/linker flags result in only a `.a` file being built - even if `-o <project name>.js` is added to the compiler and/or linker flags.

The reason is that because I've told CMake I want a static library, it uses `CMAKE_AR` to build.  `CMAKE_AR` (if undefined) is defined as `emar` in the Emscripten toolchain file, and `emar` cannot produce `.wasm` and `.js` output.

I have tried creating a new executable target that has a dependency on the library, and otherwise just sets up the compiler/linker settings.  However this causes a CMake error, because I've defined an executable target that has no source files (they're associated with the library target).  If I add a stub main file, I get an Emscripten warning:

> system_libs:WARNING: main() is in the input files, but "_main" is not in EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS, which means it may be eliminated as dead code. Export it if you want main() to run.

I could get round by adding an empty file to exe source file list (probably, I haven't tried), but this feels very much like a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that you need to create an executable target in order to produce a `.wasm` file.

If cmake insists on you creating a dummy source file because it doesn't understand that all the code for your program can come from libraries then I guess you that is your best option.

See [CMake: Is it possible to build an executable from only static libraries and no source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234446/cmake-is-it-possible-to-build-an-executable-from-only-static-libraries-and-no-s) for how to work around this limitation of cmake.

Comment: This is what I did, thankfully I didn't have to create an empty source file as I could just reference the custom `index.html` I was using to host the WASM library.  It feels unsatisfactory as the CMakeLists.txt is quite misleading unless you know the quirks of Emscripten's toolchain - but it works and isolates nicely from the rest of the project.