# Architecture: plugin and standalone behavior

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to improve the **conceptual** architecture and **modularity** of my new software using C++ and Qt.

I was thinking to develop a "main application" and **a set of "plugins" (shared libraries)** to expand the "main application" features.

I already did a simple test of this:

**1-** I Build a custom **shared library** (I'm calling this a "plugin with UI")

**2-** I Build the main application that uses **QPluginLoader** class to load shared libraries

**3-** When the main application **starts**, it loads **dynamically** all "plugins" that are located in a specific folder.

**4-** All running good! **It works!**

So, **my doubt** is that I would like to **each "plugin" can run alone too...like a standalone executable application.**
I would like to "double-click" on each plugin, or call it using the Terminal/Console...pass some input arguments...and **get it running without the "main application".**

If this is possible, my architecture will be based on develop each "plugin" like a "software segment" that is **completely autonomous** (like a executable)

**BUT**, if this plugin file is located inside a "plugins folder"... When the "main application" start, **it will can load it dinamically too (like a shared library).**

The feature of "load dinamicaly" is important to be able to **create custom menus and internal options** inside the "main application".
And in the future, other people will develop new "plugins" to this "main application". **So I can't "lock" this dynamic load feature.**

Is there any way to "mix" this two file **behaviors** (executable and shared library)? **How to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to "mix" this two file behaviors (executable and shared library)? How to do it?

It is fundamentally possible on Linux if you specify an interpreter and entry point in the ELF headers of the shared object. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807350/563990