# How to add capabilities to a native library but not to the executable running it?

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, linux-capabilities

### Context

I've done a java library that uses a C library with JNI.
The C library is compiled in linux into a `.so` file. This library needs `cap_net_raw` [capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

### Goal

Execute a java process **without additional privileges**, that uses said java library. The actual processes that are going to use the library are existing processes already in prod and we don't want to give them more rights.

To test that, I've created a `jar` and run it both with and without `sudo`. As expected, it succeeds with but fail without it.

#### Steps to reproduce the test

1. Create a java class with a native method, let's call it `SocketTester.java`

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("SocketTester");
}
private native int socketTest();
```

2. Generate `socketTester.h` file with the command

```
javac -h . SocketTester.java
```

3. Create `socketTester.c` file that implements `socketTester.h` and which needs the `cap_net_raw` capabitily
4. Compile with

```
gcc -o libSocketTester.so socketTester.c -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
```

5. Move `libSocketTester.so` to /usr/lib
6. Run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

7. Set the cap

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=epi libSocketTester.so
```

8. Create a `Test.java` class

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SocketTester tester = new SocketTester();
    tester.socketTest();
}
```

9. Create a jar with `SocketTester.java` and `Test.java`
10. Run the test

```
java -cp socketTester.jar Test
```

### What I've already tried

#### Adding cap to the `.so` lib

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=epi libSocketTester.so
```

Result: Failure

#### Adding cap to java

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=epi /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Result: It works, but it's not what I want because now all java process have the capability (see bold in goal section).

### The question

Why is adding the cap to the `.so` doesn't work? How else can I accomplish the goal?

Comment: When you add the capability to the library, have you tried to load it through the classpath directly instead of loading from a jar containing the library?

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux I edited my question to add the steps to reproduce the test, so you can see exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: From `man capabilities`, it seems capabilities can be set on an executable file. You could try to build a JNI library calling an executable file with the capability needed.
`File capabilities > Since kernel 2.6.24, the kernel supports associating capability sets with an executable file using setcap(8).`

Comment: It might be possible to directly execute from Java the executable file with proper capabilities using `java.lang.Runtime#exec()`

Answer (score 1):

A zillion years ago I figured out how to have PAM modules fork a helper program to do privileged things from unprivileged contexts. This is how `pam_unix.so` is able to invoke `unix_chkpwd` to help an unprivileged application (a `screensaver`, or `screen`) accept a user password to unlock under Linux.

More recently, I learned the trick to making shared library objects (`libcap.so`, `pam_cap.so` etc) [work as standalone binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339111/14760867). I've since been thinking about combining both of these techniques... Researching that, I came across this question. Since I was able to do it for the example task of an unprivileged program binding to port `80`, I thought it might be of interest as an answer here.

I've done a full write up of how it works on the [Fully Capable `libcap`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/capable-shared-objects) distribution site, but it essentially boils down to three things:

- make the [`.so` file executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339111/14760867) as a stand alone program, with its own file capability
- include some code in the `.so` file that figures out its own filename when linked into another program (this uses a `_GNU_SOURCE` extension: `dladdr()`)
- create some mechanism for the library itself to fork/exec itself (I use `libcap:cap_launch()`) with a private communication mechanism (I use a Unix domain socket generated with `socketpair()`) back to the app-linked shared library code.

The flow is basically, app calls the `.so` function, that function invokes the `.so` file as a forked child and performs the privileged operation. It then returns the result to the app over the Unix domain socket and exits.