# Building an executable shared library with ifort

Tags: fortran, shared-libraries, intel-fortran

There are several excellent discussions on SO already covering how to produce an executable shared library on Linux:

- See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7066
- and [building a .so that is also an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449987) as examples

In C/C++, this seems relatively straightforward; essentially there are two parts:

1. Add an `.interp` section to the ELF (as `ld` doesn't include one for shared libraries) by including something along these lines in the library source:
   `const char interp_section[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/path/to/dynamic/linker";`
2. Set an appropriate entry point when linking, using `-Wl,-e,entry_point`

Does anyone know how to achieve this with a library written in Fortran? Specifically, how to add a `.interp` section to a shared library compiled with `ifort`?

Answer (score 5):

With help of a C compiler to create an additional object file to be linked to the dynamic library, such a Fortran90 executable and dynamic link library can be created:

```
/* stub.c: compile e.g. with gcc -c stub.c
const char dl_loader[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) =
    "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";
    /* adjust string if path or architecture is different */
```

```
! testif.f90: compile e.g. with ifort -c -fPIC testif.f90

subroutine execentry
    write(*,*) 'Written from executable.'
    ! without call to exit seems to lead to segmentation fault
    call exit(0)
end subroutine

subroutine libroutine
    write(*,*) 'Written by libroutine.'
end subroutine
```

```
! linktest.f90: compile e.g. with ifort -c linktest.f90
! main Fortran program for testing

program linktest

call libroutine

end
```

For compilation and linking:

```
gcc -c stub.c
ifort -c -fPIC testif.f90
ifort -c linktest.f90
ifort -shared -o libtestif.so testif.o stub.o -Wl,-e,execentry_
ifort -o linktest linktest.o -L. -ltestif
```

Executing the dynamic link library directly `./libtestif.so` will call `execentry`, and running the link test program

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./linktest
```

will call `libroutine`.

The C code is only needed to create the `.interp` section. The underscore in the `ld` flag `-Wl,-e,execentry_` is added according to the symbol name mangling for Intel ifort (or GNU gfortran) vs. GNU or Intel C compilers.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Attempting to execute the shared library results in a segfault. I have confirmed with `readelf` that the `INTERP` section is present, but no dice.

Comment: The very same example as in the answer segfaults? If so, this could indicate how fragile / compiler or glibc version dependent this solution might be. On my system, I get a segfault unless I explicitly call exit from the Fortran executable entry routine as described above.

Comment: @Ingo can you check the entry point symbol table with something like nm -CD libtestif.so | grep " T " is is something other than execentry_

Comment: Yes, same code as the example given above. The entry point is there: `00000000000008a0 T execentry_`. This matches up with the entry point listed by `readelf -h`: `Entry point address:               0x8a0`