# Linux load executable as though it were a shared library

Tags: c, linux

On windows I map a PE file to memory, fix the import table, and call the entry-point in a new thread to turn an exe into a "DLL". I need to do the same on linux, but I am not familiar with library and executable loading. What would be the best method to achieve this, what should I look into? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [building a .so that is also an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449987/building-a-so-that-is-also-an-executable)

Comment: Similar concept, however, I am not able to recompile the executable. Also, dlopen seems to not even allow loading PIE files as it throws error "cannot dynamically load position-independent executable" when I attempt it

Comment: Not possible. The "cannot dynamically load position-independent executable" error is for a [reason](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/glibc/patch/20190312130235.8E82C89CE49C@oldenburg2.str.redhat.com/).

Comment: @n.m. well considering the functionality was there before, and I found examples of people using it before the change. I suppose I'll have to bytepatch the check out of glibc. Or write a mapper like I did for windows. "not possible" is never true in computers...

Comment: The maintainers of glibc decided that it is not possible for them to make the functionality work properly, and it needs to be removed. You do whatever.

Comment: @ZacharyWashburn *"not possible" is never true in computers...*  Let us know when you outsmart Turing and win a Nobel prize for solving the halting problem.

Comment: What will this buy you that fork/exec does not?  The point of running the code in a thread would be to be able to share data in memory, but if your file was built to be a standalone executable, then it isn't going to be expecting to do that.

Comment: @NateEldredge Shared memory addressing primarily